# Laravel 5.4 Error 405 Method Not Allowed Error

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have Laravel 5.4 and VueJs application. When I run it in Localhost it was worked but now. I host in a server it gives the error GET > 405 Method Not Allowed Error. But GET requests are work fine. But this function I'm not using GET request. I using POST. But I giving this error. I have Installed CORS also. What can I do?

This is my POST Request in VueJS

```
this.$http.post("api/sendbooking",this.booking)
        .then(function (response){

              console.log(response)
        })
```

This is api.php

```
Route::post('/sendbooking',[
'uses' => 'BookingController@setBooking'
]);
```

Comment: Did you check your file permissions?

Comment: How to check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to make a request that is unauthorized or otherwise not configured correctly. 405 means unauthorized HTTP verb in the request. Double check your route files that you can POST to the route you want to reach.

Anytime I see this is when I accidentally try to use GET on a POST route or similar.

And since you mentioned CORS, make sure all the required verbs are listed as allowed.